# What Kubernetes service/pod is supposed to be listening on port 6784?

Tags: kubernetes, weave

I'm getting repeated

NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod \"POD_NAME\" network: unable to allocate IP address: Post http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/LONG_HEX_ID: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused"

errors in the kubelet log.

Lot's of questions on the internet with this error message, but I haven't found one where anyone actually says what is supposed to be accepting connections on that port. Which is frustrating because if I had that basic piece of info maybe I could figure out what to start/restart to get things working.

Using Kubernetes 1.10 with weave-net.

Answer (score 3):

as https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/faq/ states

> Q: Which ports does Weave Net use (e.g. if I am configuring a
>   firewall) ?
>
> You must permit traffic to flow through TCP 6783 and UDP 6783/6784,
>   which are Weave’s control and data ports.
>
> The daemon also uses TCP 6781/6782 for metrics, but you would only
>   need to open up this port if you wish to collect metrics from another
>   host.
>
> The Weave Net daemon listens on localhost (127.0.0.1) TCP port 6784
>   for commands from other Weave Net components. This port should not be
>   opened to other hosts.
>
> When using encrypted fast datapath, make sure that underlying network
>   does not block ESP traffic (IP protocol 50). For instance on Google
>   Cloud Platform a firewall rule for allowing ESP traffic has to be
>   installed.

so you need to start with debugging your weave-net daemonset.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a brand new cluster? How did you install it? kubeadm?

Have you tried from the docs:

> Set /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables to 1 by running
>   sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1 to pass bridged IPv4
>   traffic to iptables’ chains. This is a requirement for some CNI
>   plugins to work, for more information please see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#network-plugin-requirements)

As per the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)